# Composer install gives Uncaught TypeError

Tags: php, laravel

I am facing this error  "**Uncaught TypeError: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Log\Logger
::__construct() must be an instance of Psr\Log\LoggerInterface, instance of Mono
log\Logger given,**"
when i run php artisan command. my php version is 7.3.9 [image]

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue last night, tried with php 7.3 and 7.4 in the end i just used the latest php 8.1 and this issue went away.